# Analysing the convergence of improper integral with parameter

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Can you, please, check if it's right what I did:

Here's the exercise:

> Test the convergence of the following improper integral which is defined using parameter $p\in R$: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^p}{1 + x}$$

Here's what I thought of:

I used, a criteria that translated in english would be: Alpha criterium (I could not find the proper english name)

So, I took $\alpha = 1 - p$

Case 1:

If $\alpha \in (1, \infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}{x^{\alpha}\frac{x^p}{1+x}} = 1$, where $0 \le 1 < \infty$ then the integral is convergent.

Case 2:

If $\alpha \in (\infty, 1]$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}{x^{\alpha}\frac{x^p}{1+x}} = 1$, where $0 < 1 \le \infty$ then the integral is divergent.

So:

For $p < 0$ the integral is convergent, and for $p \ge 0$ the integral is divergent.

Comment: This is correct!

Comment: @AloysiusGodinho Thank you !